# Google Maps snippet show more text

Tags: java, android, google-maps, code-snippets

I have a project that reads addresses From a database and pins those addresses on the google maps.

The snippet set for the marker has a lot of text, but for some reason the marker wont show more than 2 lines, including the title.

[image]

How can i make it to show all the text?

Comment: Please show the relevant code from your layout file.  Do _not_ dump hundreds of lines of code.  Instead, just show us the critical lines.

Comment: I generated the google maps activity From Android Studio, i dont know what layout to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into a custom InfoWindowAdapter depending on how much you're being tasked with here. They have some decent documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows. I've had to do quite a bit with these, so if the documentation isn't enough, let me know.

As far as what code would help us, you're going to want to find where you're adding the markers, these markers are adding the snippet data from the locations you're pulling in.  Those markers also have Info Windows that if you need to customize how much and what they show, you can do by using methods found at that link. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the onInfoWindowClickListener and through it i call on a dialog screen with a textview that has all the info. It Works but i dont know if it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Well, if that's what you'd like to do, it's the right way to do it. Personally, if I had a choice in the matter, I'd design my own info window layout, and use that instead of the dialog. I think the user would be more used to that kind of an experience when using the map. Custom info windows and adapters are all detailed in that link I posted if you want to give that a try.